# code for Duplicating information between excel spreadsheets

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to figure out how to do a macro that will copy data from one sheet titled Master Sheet onto another sheet titled 2015November but only when an 2015November is found in column k on the Master Sheet. If 2015November is found in column K, then I need all data in cells C, H and J (on that row) to be copied onto the Sheet 2015November into corresponding columns A,B, AND C. I have to duplicate this code a few times. so that it corresponds to the month of sales to create a pipeline of estimated sales for the month.

I've been watching [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mtrMG_xk4vE) videos and have tried but can't figure it out.

I need it to find the next blank row to insert it into and I need it to not duplicate any data. Any help would be appreciated! I am using Excel 2011

this is code I've been using

```
Sub copycolumns()
Dim lastrow As Long, erow as long

Lastrow=sheet1.cells(rows.count,1).end(xlUp).Row

for i=4 to lastrow
Sheet1.Cells(i,1).Copy
erow=sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count,1).end(xlUp).Offset(1,0).Row

sheet1.Paste Destination=Worksheets(“Sheet2”).Cells(erow,1)

sheet1.Cells(i,3).Copy
sheet1.Paste Destination=Worksheets(“Sheet2”).Cells(erow,2)

sheet1.Cells(i,8).Copy
sheet1.Paste Destination=Worksheets(“Sheet2”).Cells(erow,3)

sheet1.Cells(i,10).Copy
sheet1.Paste Destination=Worksheets(“Sheet2”).Cells(erow,4)

Next i

application.CutCopyMode = False
sheet2.columns().Autofit
Range(“A1”).Select
```

Comment: Which videos are you referring to?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mtrMG_xk4vE i changed the fields based on my sheet and i received errors

Comment: Can you post any code you have? Also, can "November2015" be in *any* cell in Column K?  Or where "November2015" *does* appear, use that row?

Comment: so if the sales date changes, in column k i want to reflect in the sheet associated with the month. i have the sheet i can send so you understand better

Comment: but if i change it to 2015December then i want it to move to the sheet titled 2015 December so i could change the information in column k.

Comment: "If the sales date changes...", that's not included in your OP, are you looking to have a `Worksheet_Change` event?  Also, please post your code in your original post, instead of down below here in comments.

Comment: Where "november2015" does appear post that column.

Comment: This is my first time trying to do this, i am very sorry for my inexperience and if i am not explaining myself correctly.

Comment: I think I see what you're needing - I'm working on something.

Comment: do you want to filter on all possible dates (November 2015, December 2015, January 2016 etc.) and paste onto a separate sheet for each date? Or will the dates change from time-to-time and you want to fire the macro when they change? or just run it every so often to move the data?

Comment: i created a separate sheet for every month. so when i change it in column k it automatically goes to the sheet associated to the month, i want it to fire as soon as i change it. so the projections are accurate. i want to eliminate the copy and pasting. i want it to do it so the sheets are all working together.

Comment: I placed an answer below that will fire each time the cell is changed.

Answer (score 1):

How's this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Column = 11 Then
    Dim masterWS As Worksheet, altWS As Worksheet
    Dim copy1$, copy2$, copy3$
    Dim altLastRow&

    Set masterWS = Sheets("Master Sheet")
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Set altWS = Sheets(Target.Value)
    On Error GoTo 0 ' ### EDIT By Scott Holtzman ###

    copy1 = masterWS.Cells(Target.Row, 3).Valu
    copy2 = masterWS.Cells(Target.Row, 8).Value
    copy3 = masterWS.Cells(Target.Row, 10).Value

    altLastRow = altWS.Cells(altWS.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If Not IsEmpty(altWS.Cells(1, 1)) Then altLastRow = altLastRow + 1
    altWS.Cells(altLastRow, 1).Value = copy1
    altWS.Cells(altLastRow, 2).Value = copy2
    altWS.Cells(altLastRow, 3).Value = copy3

ErrHandler:
    Dim addSheet$
    If Err.Number = 9 Then
        addSheet = MsgBox("The " & Target.Value & " sheet doesn't exist, create it?", vbYesNo)
        If addSheet = vbYes Then
            Sheets.Add.Name = Target.Value
            Sheets(Target.Value).Move after:=masterWS
            Set altWS = Sheets(Target.Value)
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Resume Next

    End If
End If
masterWS.Activate
End Sub
```

Pretty straightforward.  I tested it and it worked okay for me:

"Master Sheet":
[image]

"2015November" sheet:

[image]

Edit: Updated to include an error handler, in case your sheet doesn't exist. (Note: I'm pretty new to Error Handlers, so if someone has a tip/advice, I'd appreciate it!).

Edit2: Updated to be a `Worksheet_Change`.  Place this code in your "Master Sheet" module.

Comment: I'm going to test it now. but either way thank you so much and i appreciate it so much.. ill update you as soon i try it in 5 minutes

Comment: @JenniferBlandino - It *won't* run when you make a change, as it is.  I can update it though, just clarify:  the changes you make will be to column K, and when that change is made, you want the macro to run.  Do you want it to run through ALL cells with a value in column K? Or just on the row you changed?

Comment: what do you mean by Run throught ALL cells?

Comment: In my example above, say I changed `K7` to "2015October".  Do you want the macro to run again for the entire page (so it'd run from row 3 to row 7, copying relevant data to the relevant sheets), *or* just run the macro on row 7 (the row that had a change)?

Comment: only the row that was changed

Comment: @JenniferBlandino - Check my code again, I updated it.

Comment: one more note on your error handling (since you asked) - what happens if user says "No" to create it? You need to stop the code from running if the user would click no. Otherwise it resumes and errors out! :)

Comment: Great @Scott! Good catch, I edited it to just leave the Sub if they click "No".

Comment: I would also add `On Error GoTo 0` after set the sheet the first time. that way further errors (if any) do not go to error handler. (Resume Next is not enough in error handler.)

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - Do you mean add it after `set masterWS = ...` or after the first `set` in the error handler?

Comment: Bruce - I edited your code and placed it there with a comment marker. You can re-edit or remove if you want, just thought it was easier that way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95719/discussion-between-scott-holtzman-and-brucewayne).

Answer (score 0):

Place this code in the `Master Worksheet` Module.

I know you said your sheets are there already, but I added some error testing in case you type the name wrong or don't have the sheet after all. The code assumes the sheet names will be equal to the sales dates in column K.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Column = 11 Then ' column K

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Target.Value2)
    On Error GoTo 0 

    If Not ws Is Nothing Then 

         With ws

             Dim lRow As Long
             lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

             .Range("A" & lRow).Value = Me.Cells(Target.Row, 3) ' Column C
             .Range("B" & lRow).Value = Me.Cells(Target.Row, 8) ' Column H
             .Range("C" & lRow).Value = Me.Cells(Target.Row, 10) ' Column J

         End With

    Else

         Msgbox "Sheet Does Not Exist! Add sheet and modify cell again!"

    End If

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: We've been thinking quite the same today, I like the error handling.  I (coincidentally!) added an error handler as well, but am not positive if I did it correctly/efficiently - do you mind taking a peek?

Comment: i pasted this in the Module and saved. but nothing happened. should i deleted the sheets i created?

Comment: it looks pretty good @BruceWayne. I would just move the `On Error GoTo ErrHandler` statement right before the `Set altWS = Sheets(cel.Value)` statement since you would not want the code to there anytime before that. Then add `On Error GoTo 0` after the `Set altWS ...` statement so that it will not go there again.... (Actually the `ResumeNext` may be enough)

Comment: @JenniferBlandino. Make a change in column K for the sales date to fire the event - which runs the code. Keep all the sheets! Also replace the `REM` comment tags with `'`.

Comment: tell me what is happening or not happening? (I can't test fully because I don't have your data, but it works great for me)

Comment: can i send you my sheet lol. when i added the code i tested it and it never moved the information to the sheet.

Comment: 1) did you paste the code into the *worksheet module* where your data is, or in a regular module. It needs to be in the module for the "MasterSheet" inside the VBE? 2) if it's there can you post a screenshot of your sheet data? I can't access external links here at work.

Comment: ugh - you didn't note you were using Mac Excel. I can test it too when I get home later and perhaps fix any issues with OS compatibility!